# Stata is not seeing environment variables needed for ODBC connection

Tags: bash, macos, google-bigquery, odbc, stata

I use the Simba ODBC driver (2.3.2) to connect Stata to BigQuery from my macOS laptop. I recently upgraded to Big Sur (11.2.1) and lost the ability to do this.

I am using iODBC and I am able to test the DSN successfully. I was also able to get everything to work in macOS 10.15.7 just fine (on a different machine).

The problem appears to be that Stata is not seeing the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable that I have defined in my .bash_profile profile according to the driver configuration instructions.

In Stata, I get this error:

```
. odbc list
The ODBC file libiodbc.dylib could not be found on this system.
Setting the unix LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable may correct this error.
r(680);
```

I am able to set this in bash:

```
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/lib/:/usr/local/
```

But that does not seem to work since:

```
$ printenv | grep 'DYLD'
```

is empty. I suspect something in Big Sur is preventing this environment variable from being set.

Happy to try anything to fix this.

Comment: Is it just me or are there slashes missing in front of the `usr/local/` entries? I would guess they should be `/usr/local/` instead...

Comment: @Michael You are right and I will fix the question. Unfortunately, this did not fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you need to disable SIP, which keeps the `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable from being defined without issuing a warning.

To disable SIP:

1. Restart your computer in Recovery mode by holding down Command(⌘)-R once it powers off. Press that until you see the Apple icon and a progress bar.
2. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
3. At the prompt, type the following command and then press return: `csrutil disable`
4. Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
5. From the Apple menu, select Restart.

Now you need to define an environment variable that points to the folder with libiodbc.dylib. To figure out where that folder is, type this in Terminal:

`find / -name libiodbc.dylib 2>&1 | grep -v "find: "`

Using your favorite text editor (like pico, emacs, or vi), you need to edit your .zshenv file. Open this file (or create it if it does not exist) with

`pico ~/.zshenv`

Using the first folder from above, define an environment variable by typing this in the file:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:<FOLDER-PATH-HERE>`

Save and exit the text editor.

To apply the changes to the current shell, type `source .zshenv`.

This should make Stata and BQ play nice again.

zsh is the default shell starting with Catalina, so if you use another shell, you should modify things accordingly. I use bash myself, but I hope my translation for zsh works.

You may need to start Stata from the command line for this to fully work.
Here's the output of the command after the fix above:

[image]

Comment: apple does not recommend disabling SIP. Instead set the path and load Stata from the command line. Something like this:

```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/:/opt/homebrew/maridb/ && 
/Applications/Stata/StataIC.app/Contents/MacOS/StataIC &```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on Apple Silicon/ Monterey. At some point Apple rolled out SIP (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) and the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is no longer accessible, so STATA is unable to find the `.dylib` file.

Instead of disabling SIP, which is strongly discouraged by Apple, load STATA from the command line and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the same command.

Something like this (your paths and STATA version may vary)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/lib/ && \
/Applications/Stata/StataIC.app/Contents/MacOS/StataIC &
```