# Configure Stata 16 to work with Postgres WRDS Database on a Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, odbc, stata, wrds

I am currently trying to run some Stata code related to the WRDS database for my Ph.D. It is a postgres database requiring some configuration via ODBC. While isql connection via Terminal works, the command `odbc list` in Stata returns the following error:

*`The ODBC file libodbc.dylib could not be found on this system. Setting the unix LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable may correct this error.`*

I mainly followed the tutorial on https://gist.github.com/JonathanWillitts/7b5a519bd40dd730b98ce1ad75e859e8, trying to adapt it to the Postgres requirements for the Database via homebrew and psqlodbc. I assume the error comes from the variable export via Terminal that I use:

*`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/ && /Applications/Stata/StataSE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataSE &`*

Comment: Have you tried the remedies from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233373/stata-is-not-seeing-environment-variables-needed-for-odbc-connection ?

Comment: As it seems not recommended to disable SIP, I tried to follow the comments on setting the right path for LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, the example refers to maridb and not postgres/psqlodbc. As I am not very familiar with the path exports on Mac, does anybody has an idea on how to adapt the path export to match for Homebrew/psqlodbc?

Comment: Can you find where homebrew put the psqlodbc library?

Comment: I have located two files regarding psqlodbc, the .so file in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/psqlodbc/13.02.0000_1/lib/psqlodbca.so, as well as the .dylib file in /opt/homebrew/lib/. However, the latter is an Alias file that refers to a .dylib file in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib, which I do not understand why this is the case. But with in the psqlodbc-folder in "Cellar", there is no file with the ending .dylib

Answer (score 1):

### I have had success downloading WRDS data into R using the RPostgres package.

If you do not figure out how to download WRDS data directly into Stata, a possible workaround is to:

- Use R and the RPostgres package, and download the data into R
- Then export the data from R into Stata, see:
  https://www.statmethods.net/input/exportingdata.html

https://datascienceplus.com/exporting-data-from-r/

I am happy to share R code for obtaining WRDS data. Let me know if this interest you and I can share my R code here.

Comment: FYI, information from Stata:
- Stata 17, https://blog.stata.com/2022/01/27/wharton-research-data-services-stata-17-and-jdbc/

Also see what this search finds, https://www.google.com/search?q=wrds+stata&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS731US731&sxsrf=AJOqlzUywzUiWVPIXO4Imkm03ffMwEToVA:1674747646889&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNz9KUyeX8AhVfEFkFHSeeCZMQpwV6BAgBEBk&biw=1536&bih=775&dpr=1.25

Comment: Configuring ODBC is a real drag even when you are comfortable with the command line. Setting up access through RPostgres is a breeze and the data wrangling capability of R is going to be much greater. Simply use haven::write_dta() at the end if you want to read the data in Stata.

Many code examples here: https://iangow.github.io/far_book/fin-state.html